# OpenCV image/label rotation

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I wanted to rotate images and their labels but my code rotates only the images.
It does not rotates labels.
All images and labels are in the same directory and they share the same names as 1.jpg and 1.xml

import cv2
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

```py
data_directory = "face_dataset"

image_files = [file for file in os.listdir(data_directory) if file.lower().endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png"))]

for i, file in enumerate(image_files):
    image_path = os.path.join(data_directory, file)
    label_path = os.path.join(data_directory, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + ".xml")

    if file.lower().endswith((".txt", ".xml")):
        continue

    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if image is None:
        print(f"Failed to load image: {image_path}")
        continue

    if i < 55:  # Rotate first 55 images by 90 degrees clockwise (ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
        rotated_angle = 90
    elif i < 110:  # Rotate next 55 images by 180 degrees (ROTATE_180)
        rotated_angle = 180
    else:  # Rotate remaining images by 90 degrees counterclockwise (ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)
        rotated_angle = -90

    rotated_image = cv2.rotate(image, rotated_angle)
    
    if rotated_image is None:
        print(f"Failed to rotate image: {image_path}")
        continue

    cv2.imwrite(image_path, rotated_image)
```

Comment: Maybe I am not familiar enough with OpenCV, but what do you mean by rotating image labels?

Comment: Put the label on the image and then rotate that resulting image. OpenCV does not have an option for rotated labels in putText().

Comment: @MihailFeraru I labeled images before rotating,because of that my labels stays at their first positions but images rotates.

Comment: Rotate the whole image by -90 degs, draw text on it, rotate the image again by +90 degs.

Comment: M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cX, cY), 45, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h)